# Image won't load with "content: url()" in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a website and my website has to work in Chrome and in Internet Explorer 9. I'm almost finished and I have only one problem left. If i want to load an image with "content: url()" it works perfectly in Chrome but not in IE9. Can somebody please give me another solution where I where i don't have to change my HTML.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="nl">
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <a id="photo">Photo</a>

  <footer>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
#photo {
 content: url('right-button.png');
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior. You would definitely need an alternative solution - this should not be relied on. (Before you ask, no I'm not giving you any solution. I'm just making this note for the sake of posterity.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#photo {
    background: url("right-button.png") no-repeat;

}
```

For more informations read here some articles i found for `content` attribute:

[content property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),[W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content)